# AASM is not working with my rails 3 and ruby 1.8.7 ( undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.8.7, aasm

I'm using Rails 3.2.2, with aasm gem, I have `Document` model this way:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm do  
    state :unread, :initial => true
    state :read
    state :closed

    event :view do
      transitions :to => :read, :from => [:unread]
    end

    event :close do
      transitions :to => :closed, :from => [:read, :unread]
    end
  end
```

now on my console:

```
➜  ✗ bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
irb(main):006:0> Document.create!(:title => 'test')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `documents` (`aasm_state`, `checklist_id`, `created_at`, `description`, `dir`, `planned_date`, `procedure_id`, `section`, `subsection`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, NULL, '2012-06-16 20:03:18', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'test', '2012-06-16 20:03:18')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Document id: 28, title: "test", description: nil, dir: nil, section: nil, subsection: nil, planned_date: nil, procedure_id: nil, checklist_id: nil, created_at: "2012-06-16 20:03:18", updated_at: "2012-06-16 20:03:18", aasm_state: 0>
irb(main):007:0> doc = Document.last
  Document Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `documents`.* FROM `documents` ORDER BY `documents`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Document id: 28, title: "test", description: nil, dir: nil, section: nil, subsection: nil, planned_date: nil, procedure_id: nil, checklist_id: nil, created_at: "2012-06-16 20:03:18", updated_at: "2012-06-16 20:03:18", aasm_state: 0>
irb(main):008:0> doc.view!
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/supporting_classes/state.rb:15:in `=='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:143:in `aasm_state_object_for_state'
    from (irb):8:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:143:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:143:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:143:in `aasm_state_object_for_state'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:158:in `aasm_fire_event'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aasm-3.0.6/lib/aasm/base.rb:48:in `view!'
    from (irb):8
```

As you can see I keep getting

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: How did you create the aasm column 'aasm_state'? (how does your database schema look like?) Could it be that you used the column type integer for it? Make sure to use **string**. :)

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same issue. It arises because by default the state variable is `nil` instead of being set to the initial state. To fix this, in your case, you need to add an accessor on the model, like so:

```
def aasm_state
  self[:aasm_state] || "unread"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to write the exact name of column.

```
aasm column: :aasm_state do 
end
```